# Selectionbox of the Q&A scope misaligned

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, stack-overflow-for-teams, firefox

Today I noticed a slight (tiny!) misalignment in the team selector dropdown next to the searchbar:

[image: Example case now with freehand red circles]

On the left side there is the rounded corner of the dropdown "button" together with the straight corner of the menu. The left edge of the menu appears to be one pixel to the left from the edge of the button.

Then on the right side the edge of the dropdown menu is two pixels to the left of the edge of the button.

Specs:
Windows 7 64-bit
Firefox 61.0.1

Comment: No repro on Chrome / Win 10.

Comment: I don't think I have that dropdown. Is that something from teams?

Comment: @AndréKool neither do I

Comment: @AndréKool Yes, I think it is :)

Comment: There, added the teams tags so unsuspecting SO users don't go searching for something there isn't (for them) :)

Comment: @AndréKool You can try the new searchbox with this userscript [SearchbarNavImprovements](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SearchbarNavImprovements.user.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about that.

Left edge 1px misalignment is present in select elements in Firefox by default, and you cannot override the browser's style of the select element's dropdown list.

[Take a look on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ehow2bam/)

Right edge is not a misalignment. The select element has a fixed width, and won't resize to the width of the longest option item's display text. When you join a team that has a longer name, the width of the dropdown list will be wider. E.g.:

[image]

---

For those that doesn't have the team selector, you can try out the new searchbox with this userscript [SearchbarNavImprovements](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SearchbarNavImprovements.user.js).

For those that has the team selector, this also adds the Advanced Search UI.

Comment: Yikes! I've honestly never noticed that anywhere else. Strange! Thanks for clearing that up :)